# GPT googletag.content().setContent does not work for setting html content

Tags: javascript, google-ads-api, google-publisher-tag

I'm trying to set html content of a new element but when I check to see if slot.getHtml() gives me the html element (set below), it shows an empty string. Any idea why this could be happening?

```
var slot = googletag.defineSlot('/1234567/sports', [160, 600], 'ozge')
  .addService(googletag.companionAds())
  .addService(googletag.pubads())
  .addService(googletag.content());

googletag.content().setContent(slot, '<h2>Custom content in ad slot.</h2>')
```

I use the code snippet in this link to view the newly defined slot: https://gist.github.com/rdillmanCN/a70ec955d9a982127fefadabe8b898b5

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT :**
As per detailed [here](https://developers.google.com/publisher-tag/reference#googletag.contentservice), contentService will soon be deprecated (March 29, 2022).

As detailed [here](https://developers.google.com/publisher-tag/reference#googletag.content), `googletag.content()` is used to set the content of a slot manually. It adds html content to the targeted slot div before the generated adcall iframe :

```
var slot = googletag.defineSlot('adpath', [728, 90], 'div-1')
.addService(googletag.content())
.addService(googletag.pubads());

var content = '<a href="www.mydestinationsite.com"><img src="www.mysite.com/img.png"></img></a>';
googletag.content().setContent(slot, content);
```

Html result :

[image]

`slot.getHtml()` will extract the html inside the generated iframe. If it returns an empty string, it means your slot adcall is empty. It does not extract the `googletag.content()`, but the google ad iframe innerHTML. That is why it returns an empty string.

Warning : from what I experienced, `googletag.content().setContent()` will set the desired html only if the adcall returns nothing to display (empty adcall). As long as a banner is displayed, your googletag.content() will be cleaned :

[image]

From my understanding, `googletag.content().setContent()` is used to set html to display before your adcall is done or if your adcall returns nothing to display.

To conclude : `slot.getHtml()` is not able to get anything outside the generated ad iframe. It returns an empty string when the adcall returns an empty impression.