# Googletag is there a way to know when there is no ads loaded

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-ads-api, google-ad-manager

I have to show ads on my page and a defaultImage when there is no ads.

```
    googletag.defineSlot('/6355419/Travel', [250, 200], 'ad-slot-2')
        .addService(googletag.pubads());
```

In there a way to record no ads in code in order to show the defaultImage ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an event listener such as `slotRenderEnded` (documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/publisher-tag/reference#googletag.events.slotrenderendedevent))

```
// This listener is called when a slot has finished rendering.
googletag.pubads().addEventListener('slotRenderEnded',
    function(event) {
      var slot = event.slot;
      var isEmpty = event.isEmpty;
      if (isEmpty) {
        //add your default image
      }
    }
);
```

Alternatively, you might be interested in using `googletag.content()` as detailled [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65734308/8446708).